# Scroll to DIV on click from another page and open FAQ-dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have seen a few other questions here but none of them really achieve what I want them to. I guess I'm open to using Javascript or jQuery here, whatever works best.

Question:
I have a page with a link that redirects the user to a FAQ page, if this link is clicked, I want the user to be redirected to the new page AND to scroll down to a specific element(one of the drop-down questions), and open it (simulate a click). Is this possible?

Here is the link from the initial page:
`<a tabindex="0" href="https://somethinghere.com#q5-section" target="_blank" rel="noopener">.......</a>`

As you can see I have already added the anchor tag at the end, doesn't seem to be working (does it matter if link is opened in a new tab or same window? Currently it opens a new tab

And the ID of the drop-down that should be opened on the new page when that link is clicked is `#q5-section`

Here is the HTML code from the entire FAQ drop-down:

```
<div class="faq-question" id="q5-section">
  <input id="q5" type="checkbox" class="panel">
  <div class="plus">+</div>
  <label for="q5" class="panel-title">................</label>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <span>
      ....................»
      <ul>
        <li>.........................</li>
        <li>..........................</li>
      </ul>
      <br><br>
      .......................»

      <ul>
        <li>...................</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there is any missing info to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: I don't see an `<a>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: Oh, yea the link is inserted from the page builder not as an ```<a>``` tag but rather with the built in functions. But in the front-end, the link is an ```<a>``` tag. I'll update the question. Oh and also, the ```<a>``` tag which leads to the page is on the other page. So the HTML above is the FAQ from the destination page.

Comment: To be short: It is possible. But for the link to work as expected you want to use @byteSlayer solution. Plus you want to have a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView .-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links with anchors in them (`https://...#element_id`) will cause the browser to scroll down to that element when the link is loaded.

However, from your question it seems you also want to simulate a click (presumably to open a section or an accordion). This can't be done purely by the link, but can be achieved pretty easily with some straightforward javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Extract the hash value from the URL (it includes the '#' character)
  const elementId = window.location.hash;

  // If there's a hash value, and it's not just '#'
  if (elementId && elementId.length > 1) {
    // Attempt to find the element with the corresponding ID (without the '#' character)
    const elementToClick = document.querySelector(elementId);
    
    // If the element exists, click it
    if (elementToClick) {
      elementToClick.click();
    } else {
      console.warn("No element found with ID:", elementId);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason the anchor link doesn't scroll down to the element. But do I need to edit the JS code you just sent me or should that work for my case?

Comment: You can try adding `elementToClick.scrollIntoView()` after `scrollIntoView.click()` in the code snippet to ensure it scrolls to the element

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to find ```scrollIntoView.click()``` in the code snippet you sent, do you mind updating the answer if it's missing? Or did you mean to enter it after ```elementToClick.click();```?

Comment: Sorry yeah I meant elementToClick.click();

Comment: I removed the ```document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {``` wrap and the code works. For some strange reason if the code is wrapped in this eventlistener, code won't run. So I marked this as the answer as the code worked :) Had to change the ```elementToClick``` to the actual selector of the text within the DIV, as ONLY the text in that DIV box was clickable. But works as a charm now! Thanks a lot